# Using preg_replace to get $_GET variables

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I made the following PHP function:

```
<?php
function convertGET($str) {
    $regex = '/GET:+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/';
    $str = preg_replace($regex, $_GET["$1"], $str);
    return($str);
}
$string = "foobar: GET:foobar";
$string = convertGET($string);
echo $string;
?>
```

The function is suppost to get a string and replace something like:
`GET:foobar`with the `$_GET` variable "foobar".

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace_callback()` instead:

```
<?php
$input = array("foobar" => "Some other string");

$regex = '~GET:([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)~';
$string = "foobar: GET:foobar";
$string = preg_replace_callback($regex,
    function($matches) use ($input) {
        return $input[$matches[1]];
    },
    $string);
echo $string;
// output: foobar: Some other string
?>
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/p4pSyy).